# Control is pushed from the screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app. A screen has many controls, and I use ScrollView to let the user ability to see all the controls. I have a button outside of the ScrollView, because I want it to be easily accessible without scrolling down the screen. But some of our customers have vision issues, so they enlarge the text size on their phones. Then the button disappears from the screen. I wonder what I can do to fix this... I guess I would agree with the scrolling only for those with the large text size, if there is no better solution.
Here is my code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Margin="30">
        ... Many controls are here
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <StackLayout 
            x:Name="Validation" 
            HeightRequest="150"
            IsVisible="{Binding ValidationResult.IsValid, Converter={converters:InverseBoolConverter}}">
            <Label Text="Please fix the following errors:" TextColor="Red" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Errors}" TextColor="Red" />
        </StackLayout>

        <Button 
            Text="Calculate"
            Command="{Binding CalculateCommand}"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

ADDED:

I did not mention that the content of the page is within a ControlTemplate:

```
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}" TextColor="Red" />
                <ContentPresenter Margin="10, 0, 10, 120" />
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="20" >
                    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='© {0:yyyy} Company Name, Inc.'}" />
                    <Label Text="All trademarks shown are the intellectual properties of their respective owners." />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: use a Grid instead of a StackLayout for the outermost container.  Or just put the button above the scrollview

Comment: @Jason Thank you Jason. As you were the first who gave the suggestion, would you like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Jason , **StackLayout** will not fit the size of its child Elements . So you could use **Grid** with three Rows

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="150"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"  />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Both">
            <StackLayout Margin="30" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HeightRequest="300">
              
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Grid HeightRequest = "150" Grid.Row="1">

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        

          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label  Grid.Row="0"  Text="Please fix the following errors:" TextColor="Red" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <Label  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Errors}" TextColor="Red" />
        </Grid>

        <Button 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Text="Calculate"
           
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />


</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied it, but it did not help. Maybe it has something to do with the control template? I added it to my original question.

Comment: Also I used Height Auto for the 2nd RowDefinition, as this control is visible only as needed, and I cannot allow a large empty space.

Comment: In your case you need to set the parent layout of the 2nd row as a grid  with two rows at same time

Comment: Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The large empty space is there, due to <RowDefinition Height="150"  />

Comment: Try to set it as auto

Comment: Still no luck. The Calculate button is pushed from the screen, like before. BTW, I wonder if there is a way to enlarge text size in the emulator, so I don't need to deploy my changes just to test... And I did not use HeightRequest="300". Should I?

Comment: I found how to enlarge text in the emulator. So the only thing I need is a solution to the issue...

Comment: OK, I solved it by giving absolute height to the button's (3rd) RowDefinition instead of the 2nd. Thank you!